# Getting wrong output for [1,0] in OR gate using perceptron

Tags: neural-network, perceptron

```
def train(self,inputs,target):
        self.weights=np.ones(np.shape(inputs)[1]+1)[np.newaxis]
        for i in range(self.epochs):
            for x,t in zip(inputs,target):
                y_pred=self.predict(x)
                for i in range(np.shape(inputs)[1]):
                    self.weights[0,1]+=self.learning_rate*(t-y_pred)
                    self.weights[0,i+1]+=self.learning_rate*(t-y_pred)*x[i]
```

The above code is to update weights in perceptron model (implementation of OR gate using perceptron)

```
print(per.predict([0,0]))
print(per.predict([0,1]))
print(per.predict([1,0]))
print(per.predict([1,1]))
```

I got the output :

```
[0]
[1]
[0]
[1]
```

Please explain where is the mistake and how to resolve it..
(link for complete code: https://onlinegdb.com/rJRmz_Cpr)

Comment: Try making your learning rate negative

Comment: I tried to do that. Still it's not working..

Comment: Taking a brief look at your code, it seems there's quite a bit wrong with it. First of all, a learning rate that low for a step function probably wont work. 5 epochs is also very low. Try 5000. You are initialising all your weights to be 1, that will definitely hinder performance. There's no bias'. You're using a step function (no gradient). Maybe try drawing this network out yourself and running your code step by step by hand, if you do that I'm sure you will understand the problem better and getting a working NN